# Can Combat Flexibility satisfy prerequisites for permanent feats?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e

Can the feat a Fighter gains from Combat Flexibility satisfy the prerequisites for other feats you gain at level-up?

For example, Quick Shield Block requires Reactive Shield. If your Combat Flexibility feat is Reactive Shield, can you take Quick Shield Block during your level-up, then change your Combat Flexibility feat to something else the next day?

Comment: When you say take Quick Shield Block, you mean when you level up?

Comment: Yes, when you level up.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the intent is for it not to be usable as a prerequisite, but I've not found anything in the Core Rulebook to support this statement, nor on the Paizo forums. This may need to wait for the next round of errata; alternatively, posting on the Paizo forums might get an official answer.

Answer (score 4):

### You must meet the prerequisites any time you use a feat.

Combat Flexability explicitly grants you a feat (Core Rules, pg. 143):

> When you make your daily preperations, you gain one fighter feat of 8th level or lower ...

If you use Combat Flexability to gain Reactive Shield, then for all purposes you have that feat.

The sticking point comes from how feat prerequisites work. The definition of prerequisites is found on page 18:

> Any minimum ability scores, feats, proficiency ranks, or other prerequisites you must have before you can access this rule element are listed here.

A prerequisite *isn't* only required at the time you select a feat;  it's required anytime you want to "access" that feat. In your example, you wouldn't be able to utilize Quick Shield Block even though you have it, because you no longer meet the prerequisites.

Comment: Very cool. That reading opens up interesting possibilities if you're willing to lock in your Combat Flexibility feat, or willing to go without one of your level-up feats.

Answer (score 0):

Your question, as far as I know, has not a direct and official answer..but I think we can put together some information to achieve a good answer anyway (or at least try to achieve it).

First: keep in mind that combat flexibility states that you gain a feat (or more as you level up) **only** until your next daily preparation.

> Combat Flexibility: [..] When you make your daily preparations, you gain one fighter feat of 8th level or lower that you don’t already have. You can use that feat until your next daily preparations.

This means that every day you **lose** and **gain** a feat so we can be pretty sure that combat flexibility gives you **temporary** feats and this temporary feats are not intented to give you anything else other than the possibility to use for ~1 day the feat you have chosen. Keep also in mind that probably Paizo would have written an information like the one you are searching and this kind of games are plenty of phrases like "this feat count as a prerequisite to other feats" (*improved flexibility* has that magic phrase for example and specifies that count only towards other feats that you gain with this abilities).

Second: this is what the rulebook states about prerequisites...and yes, you can bend this rule a bit to do what you are asking I think.

> Prerequisites:  Any  minimum  ability  scores,  feats,  proficiency  ranks,  or  other  prerequisites  ***you  must  have***  before  you  can  access this rule element are listed here. Feats also have a level prerequisite, which appears above

In conclusion, my suggestion is (at least for now) to play using only what is written down in the books and follow the rule: *"if it's not written...it doesn't work"*. (And at my table I'll not allow something like that probably)

Edit: After a little more research i found this line of rule inside the retraining part of the rulebook

> If you cease to meet the prerequisites for an ability due to retraining, **you can’t use that ability.**

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -4):

## This works

Unlike in Pathfinder 1e, you need prerequisites only to *take* a feat, not also to benefit from having it.  Similarly, however, you can use abilities gained from any source to meet prerequisites.  That means that as long as you have the feat gained from Combat Flexibility continuously during level-up (which you certainly can, since you can skip daily preparations and the feat lasts until your next one), you can use it to qualify for feats you otherwise would not qualify for and then change it to something more useful the next day.

Comment: "you need prerequisites only to take a feat, not also to benefit from having it". I'm pretty sure this is not true since in the retraining part of the rulebook clearly is stated:  "If you cease to meet the prerequisites for an ability due to retraining, you can’t use that ability". So, even if you can use combat flexibility as a prerequisites (and it's a big if) you need to keep taking that feat that count as a prerequisite to use an advanced feat (reactive shield for quick shield block for example)

Comment: It's also contrary to the definition of prerequisites found in the Core Rulebook..

Comment: @Mouza isn't that specific to retraining?

Comment: @indigochild pg#?

Comment: @indigochild Nevermind, I see we disagree on the correct interpretation of the prereq text from your answer.